# WPF Set ListViewItem.Background With Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a ListView in grid mode in which I display a list of data. The grid works, but I'm not able to bind the Background property. If "FileExists == false", then I want to display the line in red. Why is this not working?

The list gets loaded in Windows.Loaded. I also added the [ImplementPropertyChanged] attribute to the data class (using NuGet PropertyChanged.Fody) but that didn't help.

```
<ListView x:Name="VideosView" TabIndex="2" SelectedValuePath="VideoId" Margin="10,50,10,37" ButtonBase.Click="VideosView_ColumnHeaderClick">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileExists}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Artist" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Title" Width="300"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Length, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Length" Width="40"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="VideosView_ItemDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Data class

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class VideoListItem {
    public VideoListItem() {
    }

    public int VideoId { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int? Length { get; set; }
    public bool FileExists { get; set; }
    public bool IsInDatabase { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two ListViewItem Styles, one default Style in the ListView's Resources, and another one set as ItemContainerStyle? Just move the DataTrigger to the ItemContainerStyle, and drop the other Style.

Comment: you have 2 styles for ItemContainerStyle , 1 in your resources which you do not us and it seems like it's the one you wan't to color with , 
and another set as the itemsContainerStyle which seems like it does nothing  , so what exactly  r u trying to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your default ListViewItem Style in the ListView's Resources is not effective, because you explicitly set *another* ListViewItem Style by the `ItemContainerStyle` property.

Just drop the default style and move the DataTrigger to the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ListView ...>
    ...
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="VideosView_ItemDoubleClick"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileExists}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```